# Confused In Nested Array Code

Tags: swift

Im just confused in to why I get an error when I explicitly specify the type of: challenges. I know type inference can determine its an array. But why would  get an error?

```
var walkingChallenges: [String] = ["Walk 3 miles a day", "Beat every day goal"]
var runningChallenges: [String] = ["Run 5 miles a day", "Beat everyday goal"]

var challenges: [String] = [walkingChallenges, runningChallenges]
```

error: cannot convert value of type string to expected element type string.

The right way is to simply write:

```
var challenges = [walkingChallenges, runningChallenges]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`challenges` needs to be of type `[[String]]` - it is an array of string arrays

You can either say

```
var challenges: [[String]] = [walkingChallenges, runningChallenges]
```

or

```
var challenges = [walkingChallenges, runningChallenges]
```

and let Swift infer the type